# Understanding an example on section 6.3 in Royden 4th edition on pg.117.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing, bounded-variation

The example is given below :

> [image]

But I do not understand why the variation of $f$ with respect to the given partition is as given? could anyone explain this for me, please?

I have calculated from $x = 1/2n$ to $x = 1/(2n - 4)$ but it seems like I am missing some details in the calculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The given variation ($1 + \frac 12 + \cdots \frac 1n$) is correct.

To see this, set $x_i = \frac{1}{2n-i}$ for $i=0,\ldots , 2n-1$.

Then you have 
$$\cos \frac{\pi}{2x_i} = \cos \frac{\pi}{2}(2n-i)= \cos (n\pi-i\frac{\pi}{2}) = (-1)^n\cos \frac{\pi}{2}i$$

Hence, for $i=2k+1$ ($k=0,\ldots , n-1$) you have $\cos \frac{\pi}{2x_i} = 0$ and for $i=2k$ you have $\cos \frac{\pi}{2x_i} = (-1)^k$

This means for the variation, that only the terms with $i=2k$ contribute. But shifting the index one by one each term with $x_{2k}$ **appears twice**:
$$V(f,P_n) =  \underbrace{\left|x_{0}\cos \frac{\pi}{2x_0} - f(0)\right|}_{=1}+ \sum_{i=1}^{2n-1}\left|x_{i+1}\cos x_{i+1} - x_i \cos x_i \right|$$ $$ = \pmb{2}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|x_{2k}| = \pmb{2}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{2n - 2k} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n - k}$$

Comment: After your thorough explanation here for what is $x$ and what is $k$, I found that the variation given is correct (not wrong) as you said because each term appears twice, like $1/(2n), 1/(2n -2), 1/(2n -4), 1/(2n -6)$ and so on.

Comment: But thank you so much for explaining the details for me :)

Comment: @Mathstupid : You are right! Each term appears twice. Adjusting correspondingly.

Comment: @Mathstupid : Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you please (if you have time) look at this question for me https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3428015/correcting-solution-of-question-6-in-royden-fourth-edition

Comment: The same question is found here I think https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2994554/question-about-vitali-covering

Comment: @Mathstupid : I may check this out later. At the moment I don't have time.

Comment: Okay that is fine for me Thank!